# Very slow query using second whereHas and "LIKE"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is a query that I use to search cities that are stored in my database

```
$cities = City::with([ 'translation' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('language', 'en'); 
        }, 'country.translation' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('language', 'en');
        } ])->whereHas('country', function($query) {
            $query->whereIn('iso', [
                'AL',
                ...
            ]);
        })->whereHas('translation', function($query) use($location) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$location}%");
        })->limit(5)->get();
```

Having the second `whereHas` with `LIKE` makes the query very very slow, you actually have to wait a couple of seconds for the results, without it it's very fast. How can I improve that

Answer (score 0):

LIKE '%...%' queries usually don't benefit from suitable index (i.e. full table scan).